# How can I close all currently running graphical programs?

Tags: systemd, graphics, display-manager

I need to manually install the proprietary graphics driver for my NVIDIA graphics card and to do that I first need to make sure that no graphical programs are running. What is the simplest way to do that?

I think I need either a way to tell my system to boot to text-only mode or a way to shut down the graphical session that is launched by default during the boot.

For the second option, the closest instructions I could find were [these ones](https://askubuntu.com/a/149224/344149) that I found on Askubuntu:

- Hit CTRL+ALT+F1 and login using your credentials.
- kill the current X server with `sudo service lightdm stop`
- Enter runlevel 3 with `sudo init 3`

However, I don't know how to adapt these to my case. I think I need to find out how to stop a service using systemd isntead of `service` and I also need to know what service is the one that I need to stop (I think I am using SDDM isntead of lightdm but I am not sure).

For the record, I am currently using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with KDE.

Comment: Does Ubuntu still disable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?

Comment: I'm using opensuse, not ubuntu. Anyway, if I ctrl+alt+backspace it restarts the graphical session instead of shutting it down and leaving me on text-only mode.

Comment: Since you're using KDE, I _think_ you can simply use `service kdm stop`?

Comment: I think kde plasma 5 doesn't use kdm anymore. `service` is giving me a "no such service kdm" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do it once, can't you just run

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

That seems to be the equivalent of changing the run level.

The [opensuse docs](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.systemd.html#sec.boot.systemd.boot) suggests runlevel3.target as an alternative.

Oh and `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` would be permanent I think..

Comment: Thanks. I indeed only needed to do this once and for that this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your issue would be:

```
sudo systemctl stop sddm
```

There's also the possibility that you will have to include .service at the back.